# Using a variable in the struct tag

Tags: json, go

How would I use a variable in a Go struct tag?

This works:

```
type Shape struct {
    Type string `json:"type"`
}
```

This does not work:

```
const (
    TYPE = "type"
)

type Shape struct {
    Type string fmt.Sprintf("json:\"%s\"", TYPE)
}
```

In the first example, I am using a string literal, which works. In the second example, I am building a string using `fmt.Sprintf`, and I seem to be getting an error:
`syntax error: unexpected name, expecting }`

Here it is on the Go playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/lUmylztaFg

Comment: Are you looking for a way of creating a dynamic type?

Comment: I don't understand what you expect to happen. That's not valid syntax

Comment: Could you try rephrasing your question? You say you want to Unmarshal JSON however you never call the Unmarshal function and your example looks more like it's trying to convert struct to string which is the other operation - marshal.

Comment: I changed the question so it makes more sense.

Comment: You might be better off to give example inputs and restrictions/requirements and desired result. E.g. something like "I have JSON that might be like `{ "type": "circle", … }` but the text "type" isn't known ahead of time but must be a parameter, how can I unmarshal such JSON into a struct such as `type Shape { Type string, …}`" (of course I don't know if that has any actual resemblance to what you're trying to ask but at least it's an answerable question).

Answer (score 10):

How would I use a variable in a Go struct tag? You wouldn't, it's not allowed by the language. You can't use a statement that evaluates at runtime in place of a compile time string literal for as an annotation to a field on a struct. As far as I know nothing of the sort works in any compiled language.

Comment: "As far as I know nothing of the sort works in any compiled language." In D, Rust and Scala you can do it. :P

Comment: @rightfold interesting... Only from an expression that uses a compile time constant as the value to evaluate though right? Then it's just like a fancier precompiler directive. Also, I've never written anything in any of those languages.

Comment: Sure, all input must be known statically for obvious reasons.

Comment: Even C and C++ allow it. Really, any language that has support for some sort of macros...

Comment: In typescript you would define your variable as a const `myObj = {...} as const` then you could do this where you are using variables that compile to strings, same goes for each of the keys. So other languages do this.

Answer (score 3):

With the introduction of go generate, it is possible to do achieve this.

However, go generate essentially makes the compilation a 2 phase process. Phase 1 generates the new code, phase 2 compiles and links etc.

There are a few limitations with using go generate:

1. Your library will not be 'go get'-able unless you run `go generate` every time it is needed and check in the result, since `go generate` needs to be explicitly run before `go build`
2. This is a compile time process, so you will not be able to do it at run time using run time information. If you really must do this at run time, and in your case, you are just adding JSON serialization annotations, you could consider using a map.

Comment: wrt #1, the intention is that the developer runs go generate and checks in the results (just as is done by Go team) so that it *is* "go gettable".

Comment: wrt #2, the OP hasn't been at all clear, but it's quite possible a (relatively) simple `UnmarshalJSON` method may be all they need/want.

Answer (score 1):

String const/variable is not allowed in tag value [to keep things simple](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/4740#issuecomment-66074233) and I support that. However with this limit, we need to use **reflection** to retrieve the tag value which is costly **OR** **type string literals everywhere** in the project, which may lead to bugs because of typos.

## Solution

We can **generate the tag values as string constant and then use this constant** further in the  project. It doesn't use reflection(saves performance cost), is more maintainable and removes the possibility of any bug because of typos.

`ast` package is an amazing tool to analyse and generate the go code. For example -

```golang
type user struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age int `json:"age"`
}
```

We can generated constants for `user` struct as below -

```golang
const (
    UserNameJson = "name"
    UserAgeJson  = "age"
)
```

You may find [tgcon](https://github.com/amarjeetanandsingh/tgcon) helpful to generate the field tag value as const.